# Clicking other cell's child element in Selenium WebDriver Java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

What is the code to be used to click the "a" element by looking first for the "td" that contains certain texts?

```
<table>      
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><a class="link">link</a></td>
            <td>1st</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a class="link">link</a></td>
            <td>2nd</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I used this code but it doesn't work.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(text(), '1st')]/following-sibling::a[@class='link']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this xPath `//td[contains(text(), '1st')]/../td/a[@class='link']`.

Your mistake comes from the axis "following-sibling". The tag `a` is not a sibling of the `td` tag. I use `..` to go up, then select `td` again and then `a`.

I tested the xPath  using http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath. It works. Beware that every browser comes with their own xPath implementation, therefore it could behave a bit differently.

However, as there is nothing exotic in the xPath expression, I don't expect any problem.

Comment: Also be aware that "class=" can cause problems when there is multiple classes on an element. Xpath treats the class attribute as a literal string, therefore any added classes or change in order would break the xpath.  I would use [contains(@class,"link")] but this also has implications too

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I used this By.xpath("(//a[@class='link'])[2]") if there is more than one element with class='link'